# multiprocessing.Process (with spawn method): which objects are inherited?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

The docs (python 3.4) explain that with `spawn`, "the child process will only inherit those resources necessary to run the process object's `run()` method".

But which objects are "necessary"? The way I read it suggested to me that all the objects that can be reached from inside `run()` are "necessary", including arguments passed as `args` to `Process.__init__`, plus whatever is stored in global variables, as well as classes, functions defined in global scope and their attributes. However, this is incorrect; the following code confirms that the objects stored in global variables aren't inherited:

```
# running under python 3.4 / Windows
# but behaves the same under Unix
import multiprocessing as mp

x = 0
class A:
    y = 0

def f():
    print(x) # 0
    print(A.y) # 0

def g(x, A):
    print(x) # 1
    print(A.y) # 0; really, not even args are inherited?

def main():
    global x
    x = 1
    A.y = 1
    p = mp.Process(target = f)
    p.start()
    q = mp.Process(target = g, args = (x, A))
    q.start()


if __name__=="__main__":
    mp.set_start_method('spawn')
    main()
```

Is there a clear rule that states which objects are inherited?

EDIT:

To confirm: running this on Ubuntu produces the same output. (Thanks to @mata for clarifying that I forgot add `global x` to `main()`. This omission made my example confusing; it would also affect the result if I were to switch `'spawn'` to `'fork'` under Ubuntu. I now added `global x` to the code above.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This has to do with the way classes are pickled when being sent to the spawned Process. The pickled version of a class doesn't really contain its internal state, but only the module and the name of the class:

```
class A:
   y = 0

pickle.dumps(A)
# b'\x80\x03c__main__\nA\nq\x00.'
```

There is no information about `y` here, it's comparable to a reference to the class.

The class will be unpickled in the spawned process when passed as argumeht to `g`, which will import its module (here `__main__`) if neccessary and return a reference to the class, therefore changes made to it in your `main` function won't affect it as the `if __name__ == "__main__"` block won't be executed in the subprocess. `f` directly uses the class in its module, so the effect is basically the same.

The reason why `x` shows different values is a little different. Your `f` function will print the *global* variable `x` from the module. In your `main()` function you have another *local* variable `x`, so setting `x = 1` here won't affect the module level `x` in neither processes. It's passed to `g` as argument, so in this case it will alays have the local value of 1.

Comment: Thanks. So with `'spawn'`, none of the global objects are serialized and passed to the child process. What is passed, besides the arguments to the `target` function in `Process.__init__`? Everything in `locals()` as seen from within the target function, as serialized by `pickle`? And nothing from `globals()` (unless referenced by one of the `locals()` objects of course)?

Comment: No, only the `Process` instance and what you really pass as an argument is serialized, (target) functions are pickled similar to classes - only name/module name are preserved. The rest of the state needed to execute the spawned process is reached by importing the `__main__` module. Only for class _instances_ the internal state (`__dict__`, ...) is pickled, which also applies to the instance of `Process`.

Comment: You're making a distinction between `pickle` and `serialization`. What's the difference between the two?

Comment: With `serialize` I ment `pickle` in this context. Serialzation just means converting an object to a different representation, pickle is just one possible implementation of a serialzation protocol.